# Weird angular issue on Samsung phone

Tags: android, angular, typescript, mobile

I have an angular app where I am seeing a weird issue with the menu component on my Samsung S20 phone (it appears to work just fine in desktop Chrome). When I focus an input field on PicksComponent and then select my hamburger button to toggle my menu it appears for a second then disappears and unselects my input field. When I tap the hamburger button again it works fine. The MenuComponent shouldn't be communicating with the PicksComponent in any way so I have no idea what's going on.

app-component.html

```
<main id="container">
<div class='banner'>websitename</div>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<div id="routerOutlet">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</main>
```

menu-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ManageLoginService } from "../manage-login.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,private manageLoginService : ManageLoginService) { }

  mobileWidth: number = 500;
  screenWidth: number = window.innerWidth;
  displayMenuItems: boolean = false;
  loggedIn : boolean = false;

  logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
  }

  checkMenu() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if(this.screenWidth > this.mobileWidth) {
      this.displayMenuItems = true;
    }
    else {
      this.displayMenuItems = false;
    }
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.displayMenuItems = !this.displayMenuItems;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkMenu();
    this.manageLoginService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(loggedInStatus => this.loggedIn = loggedInStatus)
  }

}
</ul>
```

picks-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-picks',
  templateUrl: './picks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./picks.component.css'],
})

export class PicksComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService : DataService,private router: Router) { }

  @ViewChild("playerOne",{static:false}) playerOneField: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("playerTwo",{static:false}) playerTwoField: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("playerThree",{static:false}) playerThreeField: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("playerFour",{static:false}) playerFourField: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("playerFive",{static:false}) playerFiveField: ElementRef;

  title: string = 'Submit Picks';
  suggestions : any = {"playerOne":[],"playerTwo":[],"playerThree":[],"playerFour":[],"playerFive":[]};
  picks : any = {"playerOne":"","playerTwo":"","playerThree":"","playerFour":"","playerFive":""};
  picksForm : any = {"token":"","players":this.picks};
  enableSuggestions: boolean = true;
  formResponse : any;
  formValid : boolean = true;
  formErrors : string;
  keys : any;
  picksSubmitted : boolean = false;

  focus(elementName : any): void {
    this[elementName].nativeElement.focus();
  }

  displayPlayers(player :any) {
    console.log("HMM");
    localStorage.setItem("picks",JSON.stringify(this.picks));
    if(this.picks[player].length >= 3 && this.enableSuggestions) {
      this.dataService.getSuggestions(this.picks[player]).subscribe(suggestions => this.suggestions[player] = suggestions);
    }
    else {
      this.enableSuggestions = true;
      this.suggestions[player] = [];
    }
  }

  submitForm(form :any) {
    if(this.validateForm()) {
      this.picksForm.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      this.dataService.sendEmail(form).subscribe(formResponse => this.processResponse(formResponse));
    }
    else {
      this.formValid = false;
    }
  }

  processResponse(response :any) {
    this.formResponse = response;
    if(this.formResponse.error) {
      this.formValid = false;
      this.formErrors = this.formResponse.message;
    }
    else {
      localStorage.removeItem("picks");
      this.picksSubmitted = true;
    }
  }

  select(suggestion : any,player :any) {
    this.enableSuggestions = false;
    this.picks[player] = suggestion.forename + " " + suggestion.surname;
    this.suggestions[player] = [];
    localStorage.setItem("picks",JSON.stringify(this.picks));
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.picks.playerOne = "";
    this.picks.playerTwo = "";
    this.picks.playerThree = "";
    this.picks.playerFour = "";
    this.picks.playerFive = "";
  }

  hideSuggestions() {
    this.suggestions.playerOne = [];
    this.suggestions.playerTwo = [];
    this.suggestions.playerThree = [];
    this.suggestions.playerFour = [];
    this.suggestions.playerFive = [];
  }

  validateForm() : boolean {
    // Create array from object
    this.keys = Object.values(this.picks);
    // Iterate over array
    for(const key of this.keys) {
      if(key.length < 2) {
        this.formErrors = "Please do not leave any picks blank.";
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("picks")) {
      this.picks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("picks"));
      this.picksForm = {"token":"","players":this.picks};
    }
    setTimeout (() => { this.hideSuggestions(); }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Anyone got any idea what could be causing this? Please let me know if you require any more of my code to help. Not sure if there is some issue with mobile chrome or whether I've made a mistake as I'm still fairly new to Angular.

Comment: I suggest using the mobile simulation in Chrome to ensure your mobile stuff is working before you test it on an phone. It's in the upper left corner of the Developer Console, there is a button to "toggle device toolbar."

Comment: Yeah I tested in there extensively and it appears to work no problem.

Comment: Found an easier way to debug locally using an AVD and it appears to be all mobile chrome not just my S20. It appears to be linked to the onBlur event but I'm not sure how it's causing this behaviour.

Comment: I tell a lie it's related to the resize event. There appears to be a GlobalZoneAwareCallback event linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a window:resize binding in the menu component which was getting triggered when the keyboard appearing or disappearing on mobile was causing the height of the window to change. I modified the method to only trigger when the width was changed and that fixed it.